# how to request if href have only https in selenium python

Tags: for-loop, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver, broken-links

I'm try to finding broken links from website using selenium python. I almost done the script and executed its working good. but I'm facing issue while request the link to get status code. In my website anchor attribute have `href="javascript:void(0)` So I try to get href attribute value and request to get status-code(response code) but this **javascript:void(0)** is not a link. How Can i solve this?

```
anchor = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

for anchors in anchor:
if(requests.head(anchors.get_attribute('href')).status_code):
    print(anchors.get_attribute('href'), "Valid link")
else:
    print(anchors.get_attribute('href'), "Broken link")
```

Comment: Check website's requests on how they make up a url when you click on the button.

Comment: They just made href="javascript:void(0) for call to action

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:void(0)` is just a dummy placeholder. Your website may have JavaScript which actually handles clicks on that link. You'll have to investigate your website to see what it's actually designed to do on those clicks.

Comment: Yes i know but i have to know how to stop request if href doesn't have any link in attribute value place in python